# ionic2 - input type vs ngModel issue

Tags: android, ios, ionic2

I have an `input` field in `html`:

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="modelnumber">
```

and `ts`:

```
export class SomeClass {
  modelnumber: number;
  ...
}
```

It works on browser. But when I trying to compile to `ios` or `android`, I got this error:

> [11:00:33]  Module ''*'' has no exported member
>   'Wrapper_NumberValueAccessor'.   [11:00:33]  ngc failed

If I either take out `type="number"` or `[(ngModel)]="modelnumber"` then the issue go away. 
I need `input type` to be number so that when `touch` it will launch a num pad keyboard and I need it to be databind.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use *ion-input* instead of *input*

```
<ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="modelnumber"></ion-input>
```

When something goes wrong on mobile side but works fine on the browser, it's usually because you didn't use the correct API.